# Rails 4 renaming route for "create" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

```
# routes.rb
resource: :users, only: :create, path_names: { create: 'register' }
```

Following the routing guide at guides.rubyonrails.org, this line is expected to replace `/users` with `/users/register`, but the `path_names` argument seems to have no effect whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Interesting that it only applies to new and edit. In any case, this is the work around I used

```
resource :users, only: :nothing do
  post "register", to: :create
end
```

Done this way to make it slightly easier to enable more actions for `users` in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments):

> The :path_names option lets you override the automatically-generated
>   "new" and "edit" segments in paths

It seems that you can't rename the `create` action.